# how to get individual figure and sum of figures from 2 different table in oracle SQL without repeating sql

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

I have the following sql

```
select 2 as seq, description, figure from tableA
union 
select 3 as seq, description, figure from tableB
union
select 1 as seq, 'TOTAL' as description, sum(figure) from (
  select figure from tableA
  union 
  select figure from tableB
) order by seq
```

with above sql the result will be

```
DESCRIPTION FIGURE
TOTAL       200
APPLE       100
PEAR        100
```

the issue is..is there a way to simplify this query so that i don't need to repeat the first 2 query to get the last query figure? cux this is just an example, my real query is way way to long so if possible i don't wan to repeat it so as to speed up the process.

Thanks in advance for any possible help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `CTE` it's possible to define the details query only once

```
WITH Details AS (
  SELECT 2 as seq, description, figure FROM tableA
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3 as seq, description, figure FROM tableB
)
SELECT seq, description, figure
FROM   Details
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 as seq, 'TOTAL' as description, sum(figure) 
FROM   Details 
ORDER BY seq
```

If other values need to be added just stuff them in the `CTE` without touching the main query, for example

```
WITH Details AS (
  SELECT 2 as seq, description, figure FROM tableA
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3 as seq, description, figure FROM tableB
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 4 as seq, description, figure FROM tableC
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 5 as seq, description, figure FROM tableD
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 6 as seq, description, figure FROM tableE
)
SELECT seq, description, figure
FROM   Details
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 as seq, 'TOTAL' as description, sum(figure) 
FROM   Details 
ORDER BY seq
```

Answer (score 1):

use [ROLLUP](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets.php)

```
SELECT COALESCE("DESCRIPTION", 'TOTAL') As "DESCRIPTION", 
       SUM("FIGURE") as "FIGURE"
FROM
(
   SELECT "DESCRIPTION", "FIGURE"
   FROM   TableA
   UNION
   SELECT "DESCRIPTION", "FIGURE"
   FROM   TableB
)
GROUP BY ROLLUP ("DESCRIPTION")
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5cdc6/6)

Comment: this is great! I will try it out.. Bt lets say I have a seq number to ensure that Pear have to appear first followed by apple then mayb banana which is not due to alphabetical order.. is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view (say View1) with the first two queries:

```
select description, figure from tableA
union 
select description, figure from tableB
```

Then your query will be

```
select description, figure from View1
select 'TOTAL' as description, sum(figure) from View1
```

Comment: ive tried but it seems i cant create a view with bind variable so i don't think i can use this method. Anyways, thnks!